# What is the algorithm or process to transcode HTML pages to make it suitalbe for browsing on mobile phone?

Tags: html, mobile, search-engine

If you search at m.google.com on mobile phone, you'll find that if you click the result, you will see live pages which has been transcoded to make it suitable for browsing on mobile devices, for example, long contents will be display in multiple pages. 
Is there some public algorithms or processes to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the mobile-specific contents of Google's own page, or their "convert random HTML page to mobile-yish" service? It sounds like the former, but the latter is the REAL technical challenge.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear descriptions. Here I want to get some ideas about the latter(just as @DVK mentioned in above comments).

Answer (score 2):

You can create separate css style sheets for each sized browser.

Example 1, stylesheet to be used by the iPhone's browser and not any PC browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" type="text/css" 
      media="only screen and (max-device width:480px)"/>
```

Example 2, stylesheet to be used by everything else:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/comp/20/navigation1.css" type="text/css" 
      media="print, screen and (min-device-width: 480px)" />
```

[Credit for that explanation](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/20/lectures/04.php)

Scroll down to "Mobile and CSS Media Queries" on the source page I linked to.

Comment: as per your request, edited to allow correct code formatting (just indent by 4 spaces :) )   Also fixed up the actual code to be consistent between 2 examples for easier comparison. Donations of between one and a dozen cookies are optional but much appreciated for such fine editing work :)

Comment: What do you mean by donating cookies?

Comment: DVK was just joking for the editing task he had to do for you. Note the :) at the end.

Comment: @Senhil Kumaran - Thanks. I'm a n00b at StackOverflow (just joined yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is displaying alternative content for devices, specifically mobile. There are multiple methods to achieving this - some requiring the pagination of content or the elimination of some content altogether. This can be a function of your content management system or even an elaborate implementation of some templating schemes.

However you decide to implement it, most mobile sites lack imbellishment with images or heavy markup overall. If you are translating a website for display on an iPhone or Android device you may want to replace all of your existing layouts with mobile-friendly HTML that has a lower overhead than a full-blown web 2.0 layout.

The technical requirements will depend on your server technology, your application/platform, and the type of content/media you will be serving.

Best of luck!

Comment: you are right that the requiredments depend on application/platform, etc.

Comment: However, there are still a lot common requirements like resizing large pics, remove ads, here I think this can be a web service which will transcode the page in real time just as google did.   Is there some open source project focus on this requirement? I haven't found any.

Comment: I don't think one exists. You can probably use one of the many free services that do this and begin to build requirements/features for a free open-source package if you were to try to build it yourself. Here's a good place to start for a list of these types of services http://pelfusion.com/know-how/how-to-create-or-convert-website-into-mobile-format/